# Gitlab Pipeline - How to check the logs of a runnning instance?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

I started my `Spring Boot REST API` application successfully with a gitlab pipeline. I can make a call to the application endpoints with Postman and I receive the expected responses with status `200`.

But now I want to check the logs of my application, but I don't know how to access the instance that was started by the gitlab pipeline.

In this [gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs.html), they say that for example the production logs are at `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production_json.log`. But where is this `var` folder?

And [here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/need-help-understanding-logs-and-where-to-find-them/29641) they say you need sudo access into your instance, but how do I do that? Does it mean I need to ssh access the running instance and how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out now that the pipeline is not actually hosting the instance, so that question didn't make much sense, and I found my instance logs in my case on Cloud Foundry (where I host my instance). Thanks anyway ; )